# SQL - If a value exists in a cell, use that in the group by

Tags: sql, oracle

Sorry for the awful title but basically I have this data:

```
STATUS   | ID | Num | Name
--------------------------
Active   | 1  | 1A  | Jo
InActive | 1  | 1A  | Jo
Active   | 2  | 1B  | Phil
InActive | 3  | 1C  | Dave
```

This would be the table I want bringing back

```
STATUS   | ID | Num | Name
--------------------------
Active   | 1  | 1A  | Jo
Active   | 2  | 1B  | Phil
InActive | 3  | 1C  | Dave
```

So Jo has both an Active and inactive row. However for anyone who has multiple rows and the value of one of those rows in the status column is Active, I want that to be the overriding factor

I've tried various group by and case statements but have got nowhere quick.

Is there a way to easily get what I need?

Answer (score 3):

Simply do a `GROUP BY`. Use `MIN()` to pick Active before InActive.

```
select min(STATUS), ID, Num, Name
from tablename
group by ID, Num, Name
```

Comment: Awesome - thank you - this answers the question perfectly and in hindsight, very easy

Comment: @nikhilsugandh, I can't find any duplicates in the sample data. However, if such exist, only one will be returned. What would you prefer? ("_the value of one of those rows in the status column is Active_")